# Using predefined data in windows phone app

Tags: json, win-universal-app

I am creating a Windows Universal App

In the App I need some Datalists (radio stations) which I have as a JSON File right now.
What would be the best way to store this data in my App and access it?

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-22-Storing-and-Retrieving-Serialized-Data

Answer (score 0):

Include the JSON file in your appx package (Add it to the project in Visual Studio then mark it as content) so it deploys with the app.

To read it load the file into a string (see [Quickstart: Reading and Writing Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758325(v=win.10).aspx#reading_from_a_file) on MSDN)

```
StorageFile jsonFile = await Storagefile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///sample.json"));
string jsonText = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(jsonFile);
```

Then parse it with the Windows.Data.Json classes (see [Using JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770289.aspx))

```
JsonValue jsonValue = JsonValue.Parse(jsonText);
double height = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedNumber("Height");
string title = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedString("Title");
```